# Crashlytic does not show the exact line of code and error

Tags: java, android, firebase-crash-reporting

I have integrated my app with Crashlytics firebase. The errors that firebase report them are not clear for me. See the below firebase error.

`Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String a.a.a.i.f.c()' on a null object reference
       at af.ahg.buberdriver.helpers.ride.RideHelper.acceptRide(RideHelper.java)
       at af.ahg.buberdriver.activities.MainActivity.access$800(MainActenter code hereivity.java)
       at af.ahg.buberdriver.activities.MainActivity.access$1600(MainActivity.java)
       at af.ahg.buberdriver.activities.MainActivity$17.onSlideCompleteAnimationStarted(MainActivity.java)
       at com.ncorti.slidetoact.SlideToActView$startAnimationComplete$6.onAnimationStart(SlideToActView.java)
       at android.animation.AnimatorSet.start + 615(AnimatorSet.java:615)
       at com.ncorti.slidetoact.SlideToActView.access$getMAreaWidth$p(SlideToActView.java)
       at com.ncorti.slidetoact.SlideToActView.onTouchEvent(SlideToActView.java)
       at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent + 8808(View.java:8808)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 2581(ViewGroup.java:2581)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2254(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 2581(ViewGroup.java:2581)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2254(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 2581(ViewGroup.java:2581)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2254(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 2581(ViewGroup.java:2581)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2254(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 2581(ViewGroup.java:2581)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2254(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 2581(ViewGroup.java:2581)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2254(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 2581(ViewGroup.java:2581)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2254(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent + 2581(ViewGroup.java:2581)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent + 2254(ViewGroup.java:2254)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent + 2607(PhoneWindow.java:2607)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent + 1779(PhoneWindow.java:1779)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent + 2846(Activity.java:2846)
       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent + 2568(PhoneWindow.java:2568)
       at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent + 9003(View.java:9003)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent + 4209(ViewRootImpl.java:4209)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess + 4072(ViewRootImpl.java:4072)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver + 3627(ViewRootImpl.java:3627)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext + 3680(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward + 3646(ViewRootImpl.java:3646)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward + 3763(ViewRootImpl.java:3763)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply + 3654(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply + 3820(ViewRootImpl.java:3820)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver + 3627(ViewRootImpl.java:3627)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext + 3680(ViewRootImpl.java:3680)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward + 3646(ViewRootImpl.java:3646)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply + 3654(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver + 3627(ViewRootImpl.java:3627)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent + 5910(ViewRootImpl.java:5910)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents + 5884(ViewRootImpl.java:5884)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent + 5855(ViewRootImpl.java:5855)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent + 6000(ViewRootImpl.java:6000)
       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent + 185(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next + 143(MessageQueue.java:143)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 122(Looper.java:122)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 5910(ActivityThread.java:5910)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke + 372(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 1405(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 1200(ZygoteInit.java:1200)`

Answer (score 2):

Crash log is obfuscated as it seems proguard is on.

Refer [Get deobfuscated crash reports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android) to get complete crash report.